# Selenium-TestNG-Maven - Getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver"

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my first selenium script using TestNG and Maven.
Created a simple "Hello World" code  and a selenium test code which just checks the title of google page.

Selenium Code Below with TestNG:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class HelloTest {
    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        //WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Firefox Driver\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();
        d.get("https://www.google.com");
        System.out.println("This is first TestNG");

    }
}
```

This is working absolutely fine when run through eclipse - Run As - Test NG test.

But when ran through Maven - mvn clean install from cmd prompt, i am  getting below error

```
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Running HelloTest
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.94 sec <<< FAILURE! - in HelloTest
testOne(HelloTest)  Time elapsed: 0.032 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at HelloTest.testOne(HelloTest.java:11)
```

It is showing error at `WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();`. Not sure where the issue is. Added all jar files , checked the build path and all the jar were there. Below is my POM file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo.micky</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenDemoTwo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <version>15.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: `selenium-firefox-driver` is included in `selenium-java`. See the graphic on this page for additional info: https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp

Comment: you shouldn't need to set your gecko driver path. take it out.

Comment: I tried taking gecko driver path but its not allowing as its a synta mistake.

Answer (score 1):

### What is NoClassDefFoundError

**NoClassDefFoundError** in Java occurs when **JVM** is not able to find a particular class at *runtime* which was available at *compile time*. For example, if we have resolved a method call from a *Class* or accessing any static member of a *Class* and that *Class* is not available during *runtime* then **JVM** will throw **NoClassDefFoundError**.

The error you are seeing is :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver
```

This clearly indicates that `Selenium` is trying to resolve the particular **FirefoxDriver** *Class* at runtime from **`org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver`** which is not available.

### What went wrong :

This situation occurs if there are presence of multiple sources to resolve the Classes and Methods through **`JDK`**/**`Maven`**/**`Gradle`**.

From the **pom.xml** it is pretty clear that you have added multiple dependencies for **FirefoxDriver** *Class* as follows:

- **`<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>`**:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```
- **`<artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>`**:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- **`<artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>`**:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Additionally you have also *added all jar files*.

From all the above mentioned points it's clear that the related **`Class`** or **`Methods`** were resolved from one source at **Compile Time** which was not available during **Run Time**.

### Solution :

Here are a few steps to solve **NoClassDefFoundError** :

- While using a Build Tool e.g. *Maven* or *Gradle*, **remove** all the **External JARs** from the *Java Build Path*. *Maven* or *Gradle* will download all the dependencies mentioned in the configuration file (e.g. `pom.xml`) to resolve the *Classes* and *Methods*.
- If using *Selenium JARs* within a *Java Project* add only required **External JARs** within the *Java Build Path* and remove the unused and duplicate **External JARs**.
- If you are using **FirefoxDriver** use either of the **`<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>`** or **`<artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>`**. Avoid using both at the same time.
- Remove the unwanted and duplicated  from **`pom.xml`**
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- While you execute a *Maven Project* always perform the folling in sequence:

  - `maven clean`
  - `maven install`
  - `maven test`

You can find related discussions in:

- [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823506/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-w/47845104#47845104)
- [How to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError? Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874638/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-selenium/48878160#48878160)
- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617317/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-common-base-function/45628241#45628241)

Answer (score 0):

I was using eclipse 09-2019 which is the latest one with latest JDK installed 13, and latest selenium jar files 3.141.59, I installed other JDKs to work around to solve this issue after trying all answers on similar question. Then after 4 days trying, installed eclipse neon version(https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/3/eclipse-java-neon-3-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=105) and used Selenium-Java 3.5.2 jar files (https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.5.2/source-code) and now it is working perfectly Alhamdullilah.
Also I don't know what was the errors root cause exactly or at all, but now it is solved.
Wish if that help You